# Proving IID Central Limit Theorem using Lindeberg Conditions.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, lebesgue-integral, central-limit-theorem

The goal is to prove the IID Central Limit Theorem through Lindeberg's Condition.

> Suppose that $X_1,X_2,\ldots\displaystyle\sim\text{i.i.d.}$ with $E[X_i]=\mu$ and $Var[X_i]=\sigma^2<\infty$.
>
> Let $Y_i=X_i-\mu$ and $s_n^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n}Var[Y_i]=n\sigma^2$.
>
> Prove that $Z_n:=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}(X_k-\mu)}{s_n}\rightarrow$N$(0,1)$ in distribution.

Lindeberg's condition is as follows:

> If the following holds:
>
> $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{s_n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}E\big[Y_i^2\cdot\mathbb{I}_{( \ |Y_i|\geq\epsilon\cdot s_n \ )}\big]=0$ for all $\epsilon>0$
>
> Then $Z_n\rightarrow$N$(0,1)$ in distribution.

So going right to lindbergs condition:

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}E\big[Y_i^2\cdot\mathbb{I}_{( \ |Y_i|\geq\epsilon\cdot \sigma\sqrt{n} \ )}\big]=\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sigma^2}E\big[Y_i^2\cdot\mathbb{I}_{( \ |Y_i|\geq\epsilon\cdot \sigma\sqrt{n} \ )}\big]$

Now at this point I do know I can use Lebesgue Dominated Convergence theorem due to the following:

$ |Y_i^2\cdot\mathbb{I}_{( \ |Y_i|\geq\epsilon\cdot \sigma\sqrt{n} \ )}|=Y_i^2\cdot\mathbb{I}_{( \ |Y_i|\geq\epsilon\cdot \sigma\sqrt{n} \ )}\leq Y_i^2$ and $Y_i^2$ is integrable as $E[Y_i^2]=\sigma^2<\infty$

This means:

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sigma^2}E\big[Y_i^2\cdot\mathbb{I}_{( \ |Y_i|\geq\epsilon\cdot \sigma\sqrt{n} \ )}\big]=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}E\big[\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}Y_i^2\cdot\mathbb{I}_{( \ |Y_i|\geq\epsilon\cdot \sigma\sqrt{n} \ )}\big]$

> Now I do not understand *how* this above is zero, and that's where I am stuck.

I do know that by Markov's inequality:

$P(|Y_i|\geq\epsilon\sigma\sqrt{n})\leq\frac{E\big[|Y_i|\big]}{\epsilon\sigma\sqrt{n}}\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ as $E[|Y_i|]<\infty$, and so the probability of this event becomes zero.

Any help with understand this final step would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is $EY_1^{2} I_{\{|Y_1| >\epsilon \sigma \sqrt n\}} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ and this follows from DCT. [$Y_1^{2} I_{\{|Y_1| >\epsilon \sigma \sqrt n\}} $ is dominated by $Y_1^{2}$ which is integrable. Of course, the events $\{|Y_1| >\epsilon \sigma \sqrt n\}$ decrease to empty set so  $Y_1^{2} I_{\{|Y_1| >\epsilon \sigma \sqrt n\}} \to 0$ almost surely. ].

Comment: I am okay there, I just don't understand how after LDCT brings the limit in that the integral becomes zero.  I also understand that the probability of the event on the indicator function goes to zero.  I'm stuck trying to connect how this gives the result of the expectation being zero.

Comment: @OGV You are making this complicated. You don't need any inequality for this. I hope the extra line I have added to my answer makes things clear to you. I will be glad to help you if need some more clarifications.